# Как отменить редирект на страницу action в форме

Tags: javascript, html, form

Есть форма

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="function () {location.reload(false); }" action="https://domain.com/AppClient_1.0_Boosik/admin/courierchengeresult.php">
        <div class="courier-dissaprove-comment-block col-xs-12">
            <label class="courier-dissapprove-comment-label" for="comment">
                Введите комментарий к отклонению заявки курьера
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Комментарий модератора" id="comment">
            <input type="hidden" name="courier_id" value="%courierId%">
        </div>
        <button class="courier-details-btn approve-btn" name="result_status" value="1">Подтвердить</button>
        <button class="courier-details-btn disapprove-btn" name="result_status" value="0">Отклонить</button>
    </form>
```

Как заставить форму делать релоад текущей страницы, а не переходить на страницу, которая в `action`?

Comment: Вариант А: Оставьте пустой `action` и обрабатывайте данные на это странице.
Вариант Б: Оставьте пустой `action` и отправляйте запросы через `ajax` , а на успехе - перезагружайте страницу.

Comment: `ajax` более подходящий вариант, т.к. мне нужно отправлять данные на другой сервер. Но хотелось бы как-то воздействовать простым `onsubmit` на форму

Comment: Ну если Вы просто перезагрузите страницу - тогда Ваши данные не отправятся. А на `onsubmit` можно просто повесить функцию, которая будет делать : `ajax{ type: POST, url .... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onsubmit="function (event) { event.preventDefault(); location.reload(false); }"
```

Но в таком случае данные формы не будут отправлены

Comment: А так чтобы и форма отправилась? Есть такой вариант, чтобы можно было засунуть в `onsubmit` формы? Или всё таки только `ajax` запросом сендить инфу из формы?

Comment: использовать аттрибуты html типа `onsubmit`, `onclick`, `onblur` - моветон. Лучше как и подсказали в комментах делать `ajax` запрос и обрабатывать коллбэки. В таком случае страница не будет переходить на адрес `action`. Всё последующее поведение зависит только от вас